# Transfer data from one worksheet to the next based on cell values

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I had trouble titling this, and I think it is better explained with examples.  I am not an extremely experienced excel user, but was asked to figure this out.

Worksheet 1 (delivered by software) is formatted like this:

```
12/17/2013
Hour                  Delivered
00.00-00.59           
Employee 1            18
Employee 2            17
Total For Hour        35
01.00-01.59           
Employee 1            18
Employee 2            17
Employee 3            12
Total For Hour        47
... etc until hours 24.00-24.59
```

The number of employees in the group per hour is different each day, so i don't think that I can just simply reference the cells.

The worksheets that I want to transfer the data from worksheet 1 to are based on date, so there is one for each day. (12/17 worksheet, 12/18 worksheet, etc...)

And this is the format of the date worksheets:

```
Employee       00.00-00.59  |   01.00-01.59  |  etc. until hours 24.00-24.59
Employee 1     18               18
Employee 2     17               17
Employee 3     12
Employee 4
Employee 5
```

So basically I need the data from worksheet 1 transferred over to the individual date worksheets.  I believe, the amount of employees being different for each hour/day makes this difficult.  Does anyone here have any ideas of how this can be accomplished?

Also, if there are any questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible without any VB in two steps. First step is to add further columns to Worksheet 1 that normalise the data. Second step is to create a pivot table using that normalised data.

By "normalise" I mean add columns in Worksheet 1 for Date, Hour, Employee and Delivered using formulae that copy values from your existing columns A and B. Let me know if you need more help with that.

Edit: adding details ...

Suppose Worksheet 1 has the values you indicated in column A and B, and that you want Hour in column D. Suppose row 1 just contains column headings. Leave row 2 totally empty. The formula in col D needs to say "If the value in col A looks like an hour, then copy it, otherwise repeat the hour from the line above." A simple way to determine if a row in Worksheet 1 is an Hour is to look for a decimal point in position 3. So put `=IF(MID(A3,3,1)=".",A3,D2)` in cell D3 and copy that formula down.

I'm sure you can construct a similar formula for the Date, Employee and Delivered columns.

Maybe add a condition to the formulae to say "If the value in col A starts with 'Total' then leave the cell empty".

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am attempting this, and will let you know.

Comment: Since the amount of names that can be under each hour is different each day, how do you recommend I reference my values in my new normalised columns?  I cant just say  "=A5", when that may not be an employee in every worksheet

Comment: Some additional hints added

Comment: I had spare time this afternoon and constructed a sample solution. Hopefully you can download it from https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14536497/20670805.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't a lot of data and the setup is exactly how you've displayed them above, a simple formula can solve this.

Assuming that my raw export is in sheet `Base`, cell `A1` and my intended output starts in sheet `Output`, cell `A1`, you can use this formula on cell `B2`:

`=IF(INDEX(Base!$A:$A,MATCH(B$1,Base!$A:$A,0)+ROW(1:1),0)=$A2,OFFSET(INDEX(Base!$A:$A,MATCH(B$1,Base!$A:$A,0)+ROW(1:1),0),0,1),0)`

The premise is simple. It locates the correct hour using `INDEX` + `MATCH`, then `OFFSET`s it by the correct number of `ROW`s. This is assuming, of course, that your employees are in the same location under every hour (ie Employee 1 is always one (1) row below the hour, Employee 2 is always two (2) rows below, etc). We also add a check if the employee name matches so that it will return 0 if the employee is not there.

Here are some screencaps:

**Sample data:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Of course, this is just the basic premise. If you have multiple dates in a sheet, it's just a matter of manipulating this formula further. Off the top of my head, locating the correct date and adding the correct offset can also work.

Let us know if this helps or if a VBA or the Pivot option seems best.